# Unable to locate play store after flashing my android phone to CM7

Tags: applications, google-play-store, cyanogenmod, rom-flashing

I flashed my Samsung Galaxy I5510 with CM7. Everything was fine until I found that the Play Store was missing in the app drawer. I am unable to find it anywhere on the device.

I even tried installing an apk for Play Store but that didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to flash this Google Apps (GApps) from this site [here](http://goo.im/gapps/gapps-gb-20110828-signed.zip).

Installing just one apk for Play store will not suffice and will fail as it has dependencies on other components that makes up GApps.